# Connections btw Fourier Transform, Probability characteristic functions, Cancelation, Concentration Inequalities, CLT

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis

I have learned a little about Fourier transforms and about characteristic functions in probability and the proof of the central limit theorem. I understand the logic fine, but  I don't think I understand the relation of Fourier analysis to probability on an *intuitive* level. Can someone suggest something to read here?

More specifically, it seems like the central limit theorem (as well as the law of large numbers) has to do with *cancelation* of values of the random variable above and below its mean. Fourier transforms also seem like they have something to do with cancelations of waves of different frequencies. Like, how often do waves of different frequencies "line up" and stuff. This is discussed a bit in 3b1b's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown) on the Fourier Transform.

It seems like there is some nice intuition to be had here, but I can't quite see it. Is there a connection between "cancelation" in probability and in Fourier analysis? Can someone please explain or suggest something to read or watch here?

I know my question is vague. I hope someone still knows what I'm getting at. Thanks!

Comment: You can think of Fourier transforms as the complex version of Laplace transforms whereas Laplace transforms are just the continuous version of the moment generating function.

Comment: As for reading is concerned, I would recommend looking into some of the mathematical methods of quantum mechanics such as those you'd find in more elementary books like the Griffith's QM book. You may or may not have a good background in physics, but you can always observe the subject purely as a mathematician. Quantum Mechanics is fundamentally statistics over $\mathbb{C}$. Fourier transforms there have a very interesting statistical meaning.